# Must pass hash error when passing params to devise registration/ sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is the error that is displaying

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

I am trying to pass params through a URL something like this `/users/sign_up?account=571917355`

registrations_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = User.new(params[:account])
end
```

Is devise doing something that isn't allowing this to work? I've searched, but nothing out there seems to help fix the error. I'm not even really sure what this error means.

Comment: you must pass parameter like this User.new(:account => params[:account])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Devise new

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:account)
  end
```

or

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:account])
```

More here [info](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer)

Answer (score 0):

it should be a post request and parameter has to like this

```
user[:account]
```

url should like this /sign_up?user[account]=571917355&user[name]=xyz